# Selecting rows does not work with materializecss css in Tabulator

Tags: css, tabulator

I was working on my project I needed to select some rows. But it did not work. Debugging uncovered that the cause of such behaviour is `tabulator_materialize.min.css`. If I do not use this css every thing works fine. working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/mq0L4gwc/7/)

To replicate the issue try to select all rows one by one.

Anyone could suggest how to make it work? I use materializecss in the project so it makes sense to use it for Tabulator too.

Comment: try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doublehrajput/c3rk8sq4/5/)

Comment: @DoubleH do you want to create an answer? I would accept it. Could you also explain how you found the solution?

Comment: Thanks. But it won't matter.. You can overwrite css property using `!important`

Answer (score 1):

Because "Double H" did not want to create the answer I will

1. what I asked / reported was a [bug](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3562#event-5976426575) and was fixed in 5.1.0 branch of Tabulator
2. working solution is to use this style.

check working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doublehrajput/c3rk8sq4/5/)

```
<style>
  .tabulator-row.tabulator-selected {
    background-color: #ee6e73 !important
  }

</style>
```